# How to change background color for multiple HTML documents with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website with multiple pages (multiple html files) and I would like to have a button on the first page, that when clicked would change the background color for the other  pages as well.

For example these two files (in the same folder):

*index.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<style type='text/css'>

  button {
    right: 50px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 30%;
    font-size: 16px; 
}

</style>

</head>

<body id=day-night>

  <div>
  <button id=change-background>Night Mode</button>
  </div>
  <a href='second_page.html'>Go to Second Page</a>

</body>

<script type='text/javascript'>

  var backgroundMode = 0;

  document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick=function() {
    if (backgroundMode == 0) {
      document.getElementById('day-night').style.backgroundColor='#000000';
      backgroundMode = 1;
      document.getElementById('change-background').innerHTML='Day Mode';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('day-night').style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';
        backgroundMode = 0;
        document.getElementById('change-background').innerHTML='Night Mode';
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

*second_page.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>

<body id=day-night>
  <p>Some Text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

So if I click the button it changes the background color to black for the index file, but clicking the anchor element for the second page, the background is white even if I am using the same id for the body tag `<body id=day-night>`.

Also, as a side-question: 
Is there any chance that the background stays the same color when returning from one page to another?

Comment: You can't change HTML or CSS files with JavaScript like that. You'll need a server-side solution and storage, in a file or database, for persistence.

Comment: Instead of changing dinamically the element style using js, you have to use some code which is interpreted in the server to produce the css style depending on a variable value like jsp to produce the html. Because using js dinamically each time the html is rendered from the server side the original code is load,  using the original styles. If you want to keep it in js another possible solution is to use `localStorage` and read the values each time the pages are load.

Comment: I would just save a cookie or use `localStorage` and reference that on each page. I do that for a front-end only co-branding solution. It's a cheap fix, but hey, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the actual background-color with cookies or localStorage and load it whenever another page is visited:

```
// When Background-Color is changed:
localStorage.bgcolor = yourValueHere;

// on page load:
var bgcolor = localStorage.bgcolor || fallbackColor;
```

For your example:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

  var backgroundMode = 0;

  document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick=function() {
    if (backgroundMode == 0) {
      document.getElementById('day-night').style.backgroundColor='#000000';
      localStorage.bgcolor = '#000000';
      backgroundMode = 1;
      document.getElementById('change-background').innerHTML='Day Mode';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('day-night').style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';
      localStorage.bgcolor = '#ffffff';
      backgroundMode = 0;
      document.getElementById('change-background').innerHTML='Night Mode';
    }
  }

  //load the bgColor on page load:
  document.getElementById('day-night').style.backgroundColor=localStorage.bgcolor || '#ffffff'
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. This keeps the background color the same when returning to the page. But it still does not keep the color on the second page. Is there anything more to add?

Comment: According to the site http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp "Local storage is per domain. All pages, from one domain, can store and access the same data." So it should be fine if you use only one domain e.g. http://example.com. Just test it with `console.log(localStorage.bgcolor)`

Comment: I guess what I meant was, do I need to add the line `document.getElementById('day-night').style.backgroundColor=...` on every html file? I see it does not work otherwise...

Comment: Of course you have to. How should the bgcolor come from when not from this line?

Comment: :) I imagined...The thing is I like to keep js and css out of the html files. I posted it like that just for simplicity. This solution forces me to add script tags to all the htmls.

Comment: No no - you can write that line in an external script-file and just include it along with your other code. Its not necessary that this line is in the html-file. Just make sure that you include the js-file at the end of the body so the dom is loaded

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript variables and changes to the DOM do not persist across pages or across page refreshes.
You can use server-side coding to create and maintain a session for the user.
Alternatively, you can store the background color information in a cookie or in local storage. When each page loads, check the value of the cookie or local storage item and apply the background color accordingly.

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

For example, if you create and set a `backgroundColor` key on the `window.localStorage` object on the first page, you can do this on the second page to apply the background color when the DOM is loaded:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.getELementById('day-night').style.backgroundColor=window.localStorage['backgroundColor'];
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and the links, but I'm not sure I understand the first part of the solution... So how do I 'create and set a backgroundColor key on the window.localStorage object on the first page'

Answer (score 0):

The easy way will be to use a cookies. Or local starage.
Just add a backround color property to a cookie with the button click and have other pages read from it... Just make sure the cookie is readable by all pages that need it (path=/ for intire site).
Here is some info on how to use them: 
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Good luck!